# Read file line by line or use the read() method?

Tags: python, file

It's recommended in the [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/#read-from-a-file) that it's better to use:

```
for line in f:
   print line
```

than:

```
a = f.read()
print a
```

where `f` is a file object.

Although I can see that this is not the main point that the comparison in the article is trying to prove (it's about context managers,) I was wondering what are the differences between those two approaches.

Is it better to use the former method even though I only need the entire file contents, rather than having any kind or processing to do on each line?

Comment: The difference is how much of the file's content you have in memory at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with memory management.

If the file you are working with is large (MB's or even GB's in size), then using the `read` method is very inefficient because it reads in *all* of the file's contents at once and stores them as a string object.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read):

> `file.read([size])`
>
> Read at most `size` bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining `size` bytes). If the `size` argument is negative or omitted, **read all data until EOF is reached**.

Emphasis mine.  As you can guess, this is not a good thing.  Even if you manage to avoid a `MemoryError`, you will still greatly impact the performance of your program by consuming a huge portion of your available memory.

The for-loop approach however eliminates this problem by working with only one line at a time.  Iterating over a file object yields its lines one-by-one like an iterator.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> A file object is its own iterator, for example `iter(f)` returns `f`
>   (unless `f` is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in
>   a for loop (for example, `for line in f: print line.strip()`), the
>   `next()` method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input
>   line, or raises `StopIteration` when EOF is hit

Thus, you do not have to worry about excessive memory consumption because there will only ever be one line in memory at any given time.

Nevertheless, if your file is small, then using the `read` method is perfectly fine because the memory impact is negligible.  In fact, with small files, it is convenient to have all of the data at once so that you can work with it as one piece (call string methods on it such as `str.count` or `str.find`, slice it into separate portions, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`read()` will load file in to memory, if its not big file that will not be a problem.
If fits a big file (say in GB),you may run out of memory while loading. so for big file looping using file object is better. it will not make you run out of memory and make your pc slow